# Windows Phone BingMapsDirectionsTask location without label

Tags: c#, .net, bing-maps, windows-phone

I want navigate from my current position, to a specified location using BingMapsDirectionsTask.
Here is my code :

```
        BingMapsDirectionsTask bingMapsDirectionsTask = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();
        LabeledMapLocation lml = new LabeledMapLocation();
        lml.Location = location;
        bingMapsDirectionsTask.End = lml;
        bingMapsDirectionsTask.Show();
```

It doesn't work because I don't have any label, you can see this screenshot :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoqRm.png

Can I use BingMapsDirectionsTask with just a latitude/longitude parameter ?

Thank's for your answers

Comment: Problem solved, I think it's a bug with the MAP API ...
You have to change the CultureInfo to en-US !

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this:

```
BingMapsDirectionsTask Direction = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();    
LabeledMapLocation lml = new LabeledMapLocation("Your location here", null)
Direction.End = lml;
Direction.Show();
```